# When I use ldapadd I get a response with possible options. How can I fix this?

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap, fedora

```
sudo ldapadd -x -D cn=Manager, dc=localhost,dc=localdomain -W -f /home/liveuser/basedomain.ldif
```

Is the code that I type into Fedora31 terminal and the response that I get back is jsut all the available options to use with ldapp even though I have -x -D -W -f. Anyone know why I may be getting this issue.

Answer (score 2):

do not put spaces in the dn:

```
sudo ldapadd -x -D cn=Manager,dc=localhost,dc=localdomain -W -f /home/liveuser/basedomain.ldif
```

After the first space, value for parameter `-D` ends. The argument parser looks for the next parameter, and since `dc=localhost,dc=localdomain` is not a valid parameter for ldapadd, it fails.